# why can't I see some of my folders in github?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I upload the whole working folder to git but I cannot access some of my folders.

My local directory:

[image: This is my working folder]

On GitHub:

[image: this is my github folder]

Where is my `vendors` directory?

Comment: Is `vendors/` empty? Do you have any ignore patterns, e.g. in `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude`?

Comment: no vendors/ contains some other folders too... I don't know about ignore patterns...

Comment: Do any of the folders contain _files_? Git doesn't really care about folders.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of the files and directories you have shown were 'committed' and 'pushed' to GitHub, the most likely reason why they do not show up in GitHub is because, as Chris noted in the comments, the `resources` and `vendors` directories will not actually be available for adding into a commit if they contain no files.

Let's say I have the following setup:

```
test/
--test.txt
--test1/
  --test1.txt
--test2/
```

If I run `git status` after running `git init`, the following will be displayed:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    test.txt
    test1/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Note how `test2`, despite being present in the directory, is ignored by git entirely, while `test1`, which contains a file, is noted as having changes by git. The same may be happening to you.

Alternatively, there may be ignore patterns set in a `.gitignore`, etc (refer to the comments on the question).

Answer (score 0):

git doesn't store folder changes, it stores file changes

Add a hidden file called .keep to each folder